# Knockout - one view model for ajax.load page

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have one viewmodel in a page which has 2 tabs, when the page loads the viewmodel gets binded, when I click on the second tab I load the content using ajax.load however in this page I want to use the viewmodel defined in the page which has the tabs, is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be short - 'Yes it is possible!'.
Implementation example:

```
var yourFirstTabViewModel = {
    name: ko.observable("John")
}

var yourSecondTabViewModel = {
    someCounter:ko.observable(100)
}


var mainViewModel = {
     changeTab : function(tabIndex) {
         if (tabIndex == 0) {
             $("#tabsContentContainer").load("youPageTabTemplate", function() {
                 ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(yourFirstTabViewModel, $("#tabsContentContainer")[0]);
             });
         } else {
             $("#tabsContentContainer").load("youPageTabTemplate2", function () {
                 ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(yourSecondTabViewModel, $("#tabsContentContainer")[0]);
             });
         }
     }
}

ko.applyBindings(mainViewModel, $("#tabsContainer")[0])
```

and your markup:

```
<div id="tabsContainer">
  <button data-bind="click:changetab.bind($data, 0)">First tab</button>
  <button data-bind="click:changetab.bind($data, 1)">Second tab</button>
  <div id="tabsContentContainer"></div>
</div>
```

This will work, but however it's not a knockout way! You should consider using `template` knockout binding instead of `ajax.load()`. You can find information about `template` binding on knockout website:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Also you can look at `knockout-amd-helpers`, which loads templates/viewmodels only when you need it using require.js. Here is website:
https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers

Comment: This example goes against the basic principles of knockout. You are not supposed to do any DOM manipulation in the viewmodel.

Comment: Read my answer once more! I have mentioned that using template binding in that case will be more correct, but the question was not about the correct way.

Comment: Ah, I did overlook the "not the knockout way" warning. Given the tendency of people to read sloppily (case in point) and copy/paste code samples as long as they somehow work, maybe it's better not to promote samples that are a mistake to use.

Comment: @Maris, Thank you for your input, I did try the knockout-amd-herlpers it's pretty cool, however I kept getting an error because of my viewmodel, it's ok I used kind of the first method you suggested ko.applyBindings(mainViewModel, $("#tabsContainer")[0]), however I did not make the viewmodel aware of the DOM, I just added the applyBindings on a DOM object upon clicking on the second tab